# Laravel livewire : livewire/message/postcart 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

hello i am new on livewire, now i am facing some bug. i'm getting 500 internal server error when i am triggering the button.

[image]

[image]

i don't how to fix this i already re installed fresh laravel with livewire but it still the same error. i will show my code

welcome.blade.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
  <livewire:styles />
</head>
<body class="bg-red">
    <livewire:scripts />
    <div class="container mx-auto px-4 my-5">
        <livewire:postcart/>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Livewire controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Postcart extends Component
{
    public $name;

    public function createPost(){
         dd($this->name);
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.postcart');
    }
}
```

livewire postcart file

```html
<div class="mb-6">
    <label for="default-input" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="default-input" wire:model="name" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
    <button class="my-2 rounded-lg p-2 bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600"  wire:click="createPost">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior of `dd()`. From the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/123b1651c4a7e219ba59074441badfac65525efe/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php#L34), you can see that it looks like this,

```php
function dd(...$vars): void
{
    if (!in_array(\PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg'], true) && !headers_sent()) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    }

    foreach ($vars as $v) {
        VarDumper::dump($v);
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

Where it will pass a 500 header with it. So the behavior you are seeing is entirely correct. If you were to use `dump()` instead, or do any other action, it would have a normal response.

Comment: thank you for the source code and explaining well